# How long will badblocks -vws run?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, bad-sectors

I'm running `badblocks -vws /dev/sda` on a new 80GB laptop drive to make sure the disk is good.  So far it's completed 2 passes and is working on it's third.

How many passes does it normally make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the only flags you ran the command with were `-v`, `-w` and `-s`, then it should have exited after the first pass. Seeing as you're performing a with-write test, it should be safe to `^C` out of anytime.

Comment: badblocks -swv, at least the version I've got (from e2fsprogs 1.41.11) will run *four* passes with four different patterns before exiting.

Comment: @gbroiles That isn't four passes, it's a single pass with four patterns. That might seem pedantic, but the difference is relevant when considering the `-t` and `-p` options. See my answer.

Answer (score 7):

What you're seeing is not multiple passes, it's multiple test patterns within a single pass. The `-w` option runs a single pass by default, and you can specify additional passes with the `-p` option.

However, a single pass with the `-w` option tests four different patterns: `0xaa`, `0x55`, `0xff`, `0x00`.

You can override this with the `-t` option, to specifiy your own test pattern(s). E.g. to test only a single pattern you could do something like this:

`badblocks -vwst 0x00 /dev/sda`